# Lightning Knowledge and Cases

Tags: lightning, lightning-knowledge

Has anyone got any good tips about using lightning knowledge with cases and especially emails. We were using solutions with some custom code to basically insert the solution text into a defined email template with a single mouse click.

now that we are forced to move to knowledge with Lightning, the process seems rather unituitive, basically you need to first create the email, pick the template then position the cursor and then go to the article and click insert into email. Lets not even talk about the fact you cant attach articles yet.

We are contemplating a custom lightning component to wrap around this but if there is a better more standard solution I would love to hear it.

Thanks